# sql query for fetching 10 rows with near values

Tags: sql, mysql

Please help me with writing a sql query - I have a table with `id`, `name` and `marks` columns.

If I arrange the table in ascending order of marks, how can I fetch 5 names whose marks are close to a particular name.

Comment: what do you mean by close to a particular name ? do you just want to first 5 names in this list or do you want the names of the first five marks ... ? please be more precise

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
select id, name, marks
from Marks
where name <> 'User1'
order by abs(marks - (select marks from Marks where name = 'User1')) 
limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft SQL Server**

```
SELECT TOP 10 column FROM table
```

**PostgreSQL and MySQL**

```
SELECT column FROM table 
LIMIT 10
```

**Oracle**

```
SELECT column FROM table
WHERE ROWNUM >= 3 AND ROWNUM < 10
```

**DB2**

```
SELECT column FROM table
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS
```

Comment: The question was clearly tagged as MySQL, and misses the pertinent filter criteria...

Comment: i noticed the tag, but trying to be informative, i bolded each DB name. I wasn't answering the whole question, just the part where he asked he want to fetch 5 rows.  BTW, are you Gizmodos Ponies?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select * 
from marks m 
order by abs(m.mark - (select m2.mark from marks m2 where m2.name = "John Doe"))
limit 5;
```